# jQuery Acting up with an odd number of "/values" in the URL

Tags: c#, jquery, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

After publishing the MVC3 site to the server from VS2010 some jQuery features quit on me depending on the URL.

`Hamsandwhich.ABC.123/Whiteboard/Home/index` - does not work
`Hamsandwhich.ABC.123/Whiteboard/Activities/Edit/11` - Works

Now then if I go up to the URL and add an extra slash to the end of the URL the results flip.

`Hamsandwhich.ABC.123/Whiteboard/Home/index/` - Works
`Hamsandwhich.ABC.123/Whiteboard/Activities/Edit/11/` - Does not work

The temp work around I came up with is to send the pages not working a value that isn't used.

`Hamsandwhich.ABC.123/Whiteboard/Home/index/9001` - Works

I would just like to know why this happens and if there is a way to fix this without sending every page a value.

```
    <link href="@Url.Content(" ~/Content/bootstrap.min.css ")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content(" ~/Content/site.css ")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content(" ~/Content/bootstrap-responsive.min.css ")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content(" ~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css ")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content(" ~/Content/datepicker.css ")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content(" ~/Content/datepicker3.css ")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

... 
.... 
...

    <script src="@Url.Content(" ../../Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js ")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content(" ../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.2.js ")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content(" ~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js ")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content(" ~/Scripts/site.js ")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content(" ../../Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js ")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content(" ../../Scripts/modernizr-2.8.3.js ")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
          format: 'mm/dd/yyyy'
        });
        $("#datepicker2").datepicker({
          format: 'mm/dd/yyyy'
        });
        $("#datepicker3").datepicker({
          format: 'mm/dd/yyyy'
        });
      });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change all of your links that look like this - `../../Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js` to using the tilda ("~") syntax like you have in most other places - `~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js`.  The tilda syntax renders a path to that file from the root of the application.

When you reference like this - `" ../../Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js "` - you are telling the browser that that file is 2 directories above the current one you are in.  If you are three "directories" deep, then that path will be incorrect.  That is why the extra slash sometimes breaks or fixes your issue.

Be consistent in how you reference your script files.  You are doing it right most of the time in your includes.

One last note, you have a lot of whitespace between your double quotes and your file paths in some of your references.  Clean out the white space as it looks cleaner and prevents any weird issues that may arise going forward.

Comment: Can't believe looked over that.. a lot. Thank you for your help. Also i believe the white space was from the tidy button in the code input.